# dot2tex and math mode

Tags: math-mode, graphs

I have successfully installed `dot2texi` but I'm facing an issue with the math mode. The sign `(_)` in math mode works fine however other symbols do not work. For example it ignores the bar over `b` in the following example.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{dot2texi}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{verbatim@out}{\newwrite\verbatim@out}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{dot2tex}[tikz,options=-t math]
digraph G {
a\bar{b} -> c;
}
\end{dot2tex}

\end{document}
```

is there anyway to fix this? Also, is it possible to write regular LaTeX and `$$` in the `dot2texi` without worring about define it as math/verbatim/raw mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not using correct `dot` language.

Underscores in node names work fine indeed, as node names have to consist of digits, letters, and underscores, not starting with a digit. Your graph defines nodes a, bar, b, and c, where b is contained in a subgraph.

What you actually want to achieve is probably:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{dot2texi}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{verbatim@out}{\newwrite\verbatim@out}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{dot2tex}[tikz,options=-t math]
digraph G {
n0[label="a\bar{b}"];
n0 -> c;
}
\end{dot2tex}
\end{document}
```

which yields

[image: sample output]

Regarding your second question, you can put LaTeX commands, including math stuff (`$...$`) in any label if you add them as `texlbl` attributes, see the `dot2tex` manual for details. But remember that the graph must still be defined in valid `dot` language.